# In Word 2010, how do you have copy at 45 degrees?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I'm transferring an Excel document with headers at 45 degrees to a Word doc (2010).  the paste transfers the line to horizontal which takes up too much space.  How do I keep the 45 degrees angle?

Answer (score 2):

MS Word doesn't have an option to change the text orientation 45 degrees...

Probably your best option is to insert the Excel file as an object.

In Word 2010 go to the Insert ribbon, then click object, choose Create from File, and navigate to your file.

(This also gives you the option to link to the file - which might be useful if you are going to be making changes to the Excel file... any changes you make will show up the next time you open/refresh the Word doc. The downside is that it makes your Word doc less "portable", e.g., if you send it to someone else and they don't have the Excel file in the same place as you it won't work.)

Comment: I was afraid this was the answer.  Thank you!